# [Rxjs]How to group multiple sync event and trigger the subscriber only once in Rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

I have diamond stream dependency and a single event transform to multiple then combine into one, but triggers multiple times.

I want to group them into single output.

I have found a solution but I'm not sure if it's right way to do it or anti-pattern.

And what's the recommanded way to achieve this if my solution maybe dirty?

original

```js
const obs1 = new Subject<number>();
const obs2 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v + 1));
const obs3 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v * 2));
const obs4 = combineLatest(obs1, obs2, obs3);
obs4.subscribe(console.log);

interval(2000)
    .pipe(take(3))
    .subscribe(obs1);
```

outputs:

```
(3) [0, 1, 0]
(3) [1, 1, 0]
(3) [1, 2, 0]
(3) [1, 2, 2]
(3) [2, 2, 2]
(3) [2, 3, 2]
(3) [2, 3, 4]
```

my solution

```js
const obs1 = new Subject<number>();
const obs2 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v + 1));
const obs3 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v * 2));
const obs4 = combineLatest(obs1, obs2, obs3).pipe(
    switchMap(v => of(v, asapScheduler)),
);
obs4.subscribe(console.log);

interval(2000)
    .pipe(take(3))
    .subscribe(obs1);
```

outputs(also expected):

```
(3) [0, 1, 0]
(3) [1, 2, 2]
(3) [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is called Glitches, it's actually a common challenge of implementing [Reactive Programming - Glitches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming#Glitches)

And it's expected behavior to have glitches without specific premise.[rx-glitches-arent-actually-a-problem by André Staltz](https://staltz.com/rx-glitches-arent-actually-a-problem.html)

---

When handling event, it's expected to have the intermediate trigger of handlers, user are responsible to solve the problem and provide the correct event sequence.

But when binding the data from model to view, the reactivity in this scenario is all about the fact that [**any view update should be triggered by IO effect, such as user input, timer, request handler**], instead of a generic problem.

---

And [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) has solved the glitches in this area, with a design of **transaction**. This design provided a default behavior to solve glitches.

But it's just one approach to solve the problem of glitches(specially designed to provide reactivity to data and derived data), it doesn't means all glitches should be resolved the same way, it depends on the actual scenario.

Comment: Oops! I just find this is my own question years ago!..I didn't notice it at all, until today(2022-09-26)when I get a notification from a vote up by someone, it's the first time I open stackoverflow after my GCS operation at 22nd Aug... lol..

Answer (score 0):

IMO `combineLatest` multiple observables that have the same source and are sync is an 'antipattern'. Obviously this can happen, and sometimes you actually don't know if that observables are sync o not.

Your solution is totally okay, but my preferred solution here is use **`debounceTime(0)`**. It will do exactly the same as your code but cleaner IMO.

```
const obs1 = new Subject<number>();
const obs2 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v + 1));
const obs3 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v * 2));
const obs4 = combineLatest(obs1, obs2, obs3).pipe(
    debounceTime(0)
);
obs4.subscribe(console.log);

interval(2000)
    .pipe(take(3))
    .subscribe(obs1);
```

Although, before put that, I will think a little bit if that `combineLatest` is **100% necessary**, most of this ones could be avoided with other techniques.This would be the best solution.

For example making all the transformations in the same observable:

```
const obs1 = new Subject<number>();
const obs4 = obs1.pipe(map((v) => [v, v + 1, v * 2])
obs4.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: What if I want to reuse the intermediate stream somewhere else?
Should I reuse transform function instead of observable?

Comment: Yep, reusing the transform functions is a good approach to solve the problem, is clean & safe. In case the transform function is too costly to be executed more than one time (that would not happen 99.99% of the time) there are techniques like memoization that could help... but it would be a really specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just transforming input values, why not do something like

```js
interval(2000)
    .pipe(
        take(3),
        map(val => ([val, val + 1, val * 2])),
    )
    .subscribe(array => console.log(array));
```

Or are your real datasources not just transformations?

Alternatively, if you need all three sources and want to combine the latest values, `withLatestFrom` could be a good choice, which also results in your expected output:

```js
const obs1 = new Subject<number>();
const obs2 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v + 1));
const obs3 = obs1.pipe(map(v => v * 2));
const obs4 = obs1.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(obs2, obs3)
);
obs4.subscribe(console.log);

interval(2000)
    .pipe(take(3))
    .subscribe(obs1);
```

Comment: Actually I'm not use obs2 & obs3 only for generate obs4, this is just a minimum example.
I use obs2 somewhere I don't need obs3. So I reuse obs2 to create obs4.
I meet diamond stream dependency when I want to enhance the code readablity.
But there comes the problem to sync them into one update.

Comment: See my edited answer including `withLatestFrom`, which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I test it, it looks like only obs1 trigger the subscriber, but can carry latest data from obs2 and obs3.
If I have only one source, this works fine and actually no different with a single subscription to the root source with some selector like in redux we subscribe to the whole state.
But when there are multiple sources, I maybe not know whether they are sync or not. So my question might not accurate enough. Still thanks for your answer.